# Создание нового треда в методе класса

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть метод класса `serve_forever`:

```
void ThreadedServer::serve_forever() {
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(client_addr);
    while(true) {
        int client_sock = accept(server_socket, (sockaddr *) &client_addr, &len);

        // Make new thread here...
        std::thread(handle_request, client_sock, client_addr);
    }
}
```

И метод `handle_request`:

```
void ThreadedServer::handle_request(int client_socket, sockaddr_in client_addr) {
    // DO STUFF
    close(client_socket);
}
```

Я пытаюсь запустить функцию-член `handle_request` в отдельном потоке, но получаю такаю ошибку:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        std::thread(handle_request, client_sock, client_addr);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: первый параметр в конструкторе `std::thread` это адрес функции которая будет выполняться в отдельном потоке, а `handle_request` у вас это имя метода. Даже не адрес, а просто имя. Погуглите про `std::bind`.

Comment: @cybrex, ты что-то не то про имя говоришь.

Comment: -1 ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: @Arkady к чему ваш комментарий?

Comment: @0x1337 объяснил, почему минусанул.

Answer (score 3):

Решение проблемы:

```
std::thread(&ThreadedServer::handle_request, this, client_sock, client_addr);
```